# Excel code to link range cells' colour into another

Tags: excel, colors, formatting, conditional-statements, vba

I am building a residential stacking plan in which each cell = unit type with specific color given conditional formatting.
2 tables follow below for each unit reflect a sqm size and a $ value.

I need to reflect **only** the cells' color into the following tables.

I need a dynamic solution and would prefer avoiding vba (since I'm not proficient), but will use if necessary. Thanks in advance!

[Find Image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omvdR.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Could you provide a sample image?

Comment: Static is easy to do, just copy the formatting. However doing this dynamic would definitly require VBA, or copy the conditional formatting to the second table as well.

Comment: It is possible to do this using conditional formatting but it would help to see the spreadsheet so that I can advice further.

Comment: @CMArg I added the picture 
Luuklag, I need dynamic :/
Rob Anthony, Please see the picture :)

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @RobAnthony long story short guys, I need the third table to mimic the second one in terms of cell colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your Conditional formatting as normal on the first table like this:

[image: Conditional formatting]

Note my table starts at cell C4 but yours is in a different place and should be adjusted accordingly. make sure you DON'T have the $ symbol on the formula in the rule but you do have it on the 'Applies to' section

Now copy and paste this formatting onto the second table.

Finally edit the formulas in the conditional formatting so that they point to the starting cell of the FIRST table. It should look like this:

[image: 2nd Table Conditional formatting]

Note that the formatting 'Applies to' the second table but refers in the Formula to the values in the first table.

The result is this:

[image: Final result]

You can repeat this for other tables if you need to.

As you are working in Excel 2003(!), follow the following steps:

1. Select the cells in the second table.
2. In the menu, choose Format - Conditional Formatting.
3. In the Conditional Formatting box, choose **Formula Is**.
4. In the text box, enter the cell reference of the FIRST table (eg C4="4+"), do not enter any $ symbols.
5. Click the Format button and select the background fill to match the one in the first table.
6. Add the other conditions in the same way by clicking the Add>> button.

Comment: It will still work. I will add an update at the end.

Comment: I didn't know that conditions and formatting can be in different ranges. +1

Comment: @SandroDabaghian Please accept Rob's answer if it fit your needs. Thats the way we say "thank you" here...:)

Comment: @CMArg thanks for letting me know. Still new on this forum :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the color code values (B21:B26) from `2 rooms` to `2` (to match your second table), the following should do the trick. Basically, this code is not using conditional formating. Getting the color from conditional formating can be somewhat laborious and tricky (google "excel vba find color conditional formatting"). Instead, the present code reads the color in your Color Code cells, and apply it to the other two ranges.

```
Private Sub BckgndColor()
    Dim ColorCodeRange As Range
    Dim NoOfRooms As Range
    Dim CellColorIndex As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Object

    Set ColorCodeRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B21:B26")
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Add the pairs (value, color) to dictionary
    For Each c In ColorCodeRange.Cells
        d.Add c.Value, c.Interior.ColorIndex
    Next

    Set NoOfRooms = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M25:V36") 'Here the range of Table 2 (M25:V36 in your example)
    'Scan range, and assign color
    For Each c In NoOfRooms.Cells
        If d.Exists(c.Value) Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = d(c.Value)
            c.Offset(16, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = d(c.Value) 'If Table 3 is always 16 rows down, this shoud work
        End If
    Next

    Set d = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to all, problem sorted with conditional formatting!

Answer (score 0):

I gave the option data validation list in sheet 2, while I selecting the option by list the cells will change . for  that cells I want to get color also from source table in sheet1 to sheet2 .